# angular sub components update a list in the parent component

Tags: angular, components, parent

I Have a parent component which queries a service to get a list of bus companies:

```
     getBusCompanies(){
      this.busCompanyService.getAll().subscribe(
      data => {this.busCompanies = data}
        );  
      }
```

When you add a new bus company I use a sub-component which has a form to create a new bus company.
The new bus company is created but the parent list is not updated. It is only updated it I press the save button in the child component two times but then two bus companies are created, so i am always one behind if you get my meaning.

i have tried:

- @Output and after you press save in the child it calls a method in
  the parent to get the bus company data again from the service.
- the ngOnChange method.

How can the bis company list in the parent component update after you save new bus company in the child component?

here is the post code:

```
<mat-card>
 <form #busCompanyForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(busCompanyForm.value)">
  <mat-card-header>
   <mat-card-title><h2>{{busCompany.id ? 'Edit' : 'Add'}} BusCompany</h2> 
   </mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
 <mat-card-content>
   <input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="busCompany.id" name="id" #id> 
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Bus Company Name" 
       [(ngModel)]="busCompany.name"
           required name="name" #name>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Bus Company email" 
    [(ngModel)]="busCompany.email"
             required name="email" #email>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Bus Company Address" 
         [(ngModel)]="busCompany.address"
               required name="address" #address>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="Bus Company phone" 
          [(ngModel)]="busCompany.phone"
                 required name="phone" #phone>
        </mat-form-field>
</mat-card-content>
<h1>testing id {{busCompany.id}}</h1>
<mat-card-actions>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit"
          [disabled]="!busCompanyForm.form.valid" 
          (click)="saved();">Save</button>
  <button mat-raised-button color="secondary" 
    (click)="remove(busCompany.id)"
          *ngIf="busCompany.id" type="button">Delete</button>
   <a mat-button routerLink="/bus-company-list">Cancel</a>
   <a mat-button [routerLink]="['/route-edit',{busCompanyId: 
    busCompany.href}]">Create a Route</a>
   </mat-card-actions>
   <mat-card-footer>
  <div class="giphy">
    <img   
  src="https://d1rw89lz12ur5s.cloudfront.net
 /photo/pinkgorillagames/file/b228d784b1ad244
 c2afc90dfb37ee277/large/Zelda%20Phantom%20H
 ourglass%20Link%20Small%20Plush.jpg" alt="test image">
       </div>
     </mat-card-footer>
   </form>
</mat-card>
```

when the user clicks on save in the child component there is a method call to the parent component to query the bus company service.

I have a walk around but I don't think it is the correct way of making this work:

```
    // method called from the child component after save is pressed
    // this will wait for 1 sec the get the bus companies 
   // needed to do this because the list was not updating 
 myMethod() {
       timer(1000).subscribe(t =>
       this.getBusCompanies()
        );

       timer(1000).subscribe(t =>
       this.showEdit = false
        );  
        }
```

the above works and you can see the bus company list populate with the new bus comapny after one second.

I don't understand why I need to wait before firing the call to the bus service.

If you subscribe to a service does the list update when changes are made?

Comment: When you click save, you can either: 1) after confirmation that the new bus has been saved in the db, add the new bus to the bus list in the front-end 2) or query the new updated list.

Comment: I have tried both but the parent component does not update

Comment: Can you post the post function code in the sub component? I would also the state of the browser, meaning you have to check how both components interact with each other. Where exactly your post action is fired in the view? I can only help if I know exactly the behaviour of your components. Maybe this link can give you a pointer => https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Could you please provide additional relevant code from your component. How does the getAll() method work. Do you use caching?

Comment: the get all method queries a back-end API and receives a list of bus companies back.

Answer (score 0):

it waits for the API to finish the process in the backend before it populates but you can populate the list in the front-end with push, which makes it instantly but I would rely on the back-end because you might wanna make sure that the new bus company has been saved in the db before you confirm it to the user in the front-end.

You can update the new list soon as you get the OK response like this:

```
createBusCompany(){
        //You can also pass data in the function
        this._busCompanyService.post(this.busCompany)
        .subscribe(busDataResult => {
            //Update list
            this.busCompanies.push(this.busCompany);
            this.clear();
        }, error => {
            //Do not update list if there is an error
        });
    }
```